# Changing the timestamp of an "anonymous" symlink by file descriptor

Tags: file-descriptors

The `futime*` family of functions is implemented with

```c
utimensat(fd, NULL, time, 0)
```

while the `lutime*` ones are implemented with

```c
utimensat(AT_FDCWD, path, time, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW)
```

My best guess from the "Obtaining a file descriptor that refers to a symbolic link" section of https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html is that:

```c
int fd = open(path, O_PATH | O_NOFOLLOW);
utimensat(fd, NULL, time, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);
```

ought to be the best of both worlds, but sadly it is not.

Try variations of

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <syscall.h>

#define __NR_openat 257
#define __NR_utimensat 280

struct flags
{
   char o_path;
   char o_nofollow;
   char at_symlink_nofollow;
};

int isX(char c, int flag)
{
    return c == 'x' ? flag : 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    assert(argc == 3);
    const char *path = argv[1];
    assert(strlen(argv[2]) == 3);
    struct flags flags = * (const struct flags *) argv[2];

    // Open the file without following symbolic links
    int fd = openat(AT_FDCWD, path,
        isX(flags.o_path, O_PATH) |
        isX(flags.o_nofollow, O_NOFOLLOW));
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Prepare the time values for access and modification times
    struct timespec times[2] = {
        {
            .tv_sec = 0,
            .tv_nsec = 0,
        },
        {
            .tv_sec = 0,
            .tv_nsec = 0,
        },
    };

    // Update file times using utimensat
    if (syscall(__NR_utimensat, fd, NULL, times,
        isX(flags.at_symlink_nofollow, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW)) == -1)
    {
        perror("utimensat");
        close(fd);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(fd);
    printf("File timestamps updated successfully.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and script

```bash
rm -f foo bar
touch foo
ln -s foo bar

for f in foo bar; do
    for y in ooo oox oxo xoo oxx xxo xxx; do
        echo -n "$f $y: "
        ./a.out "$f" "$y";
    done;
done
ls -la foo bar
```

one will see that unfortunately under no combination will set the time stamp on the symlink itself:

```
$ ./flutimes.sh
foo ooo: File timestamps updated successfully.
foo oox: utimensat: Invalid argument
foo oxo: File timestamps updated successfully.
foo xoo: utimensat: Bad file descriptor
foo oxx: utimensat: Invalid argument
foo xxo: utimensat: Bad file descriptor
foo xxx: utimensat: Invalid argument
bar ooo: File timestamps updated successfully.
bar oox: utimensat: Invalid argument
bar oxo: open: Symbolic link loop
bar xoo: utimensat: Bad file descriptor
bar oxx: open: Symbolic link loop
bar xxo: utimensat: Bad file descriptor
bar xxx: utimensat: Invalid argument
```

I suppose I am asking is there any reason this can't be made to work? Shouldn't `O_PATH | O_NOFOLLOW` and `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` be good friends, working with every syscall that supports the latter? Or would it be better to replace `O_PATH` with something like an `O_METADATA_ONLY`?

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the test case you assembled, where you create both text and symlink entries then compare their reported times.

Comment: Added example, tested to answer my original question, so edited to make it more a question of design than simple factual "does it work?".

Comment: `utimensat` is a libc function in this case and the libc-wrapper denies NULL as a pathname. See the notes-section in `man 2 utimensat`

Comment: @stoney good call, but I think Musl didn't do that, and I tried with that too? Perhaps I misread the Musl sources however.

Comment: AFAIK musl has the same behaviour for portability.

Comment: I guess we need to try a raw syscall version then to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: See edits, it's not Musl, it's libc itself.